# HTML email links in Android Outlook app turning blue

Tags: android, html, css, outlook, html-email

I have two links in my html newsletter that turn to the default blue no matter what I seem to do. Anyone know of any fixes.

The `<span>`, `<font>` and `<strong>` tags were all fixes I've read about but none seem to work.

[Blue Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq46g.png)

```css
a {font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:16px; color: #EF8152 !important;; font-weight:300; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="margin:10px 0px 40px 0px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #EF8152 !important; color: #EF8152; font-weight:300; line-height:1.0em; font-size:1em; text-align:center;">
  <span style="color:#EF8152 !important; color: #EF8152;">
    <font color="#EF8152">
      <strong style="text-decoration: none; color: #EF8152 !important; color: #EF8152;">
        View in web browser.
      </strong>
    </font>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: do you have a `a:visited` somewhere taking over? you could also try changing in your `a` to `a:link`

Comment: @Fred -ii- No. Its the weirdest thing and I can not for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: however, you have some inline styling in your html and that could have advserse effects and other styles in span. That or check your settings; maybe something in your mobile (outlook app) is overriding it.

Comment: the code you posted works well, i am thinking you have another class somewhere in your code that is overwriting your styles

Comment: @Fred -ii- Are you refering to the style="color:#EF8152 !important; color: #EF8152;"? That was another fix I read about but didn't work either.

Comment: view it on a regular machine (home pc) and see what the results are. If they behave as they should, then it's something to do with your mobile settings overriding it. Check on a pc and use the css developer tools to check off any settings. If it changes to what it's supposed to be, then you'll know which rule to go after. There may also be something in your HTML head/other stylesheet overriding it or in a @media rule. Best I can offer here.

Comment: @Fred -ii- It works in Yahoo Web Mail, Outlook web, Outlook PC and Mac, gmail web and apps, iOS Mail and Outlook App, and it works in Android's default mail client.

Comment: Sorry Brian, wish I could be of more help.

Comment: No problem thanks @Fred -ii- for your time.

Comment: Hi Brian, You code has two semi colons, have you tried removing one? `color: #EF8152 !important;;`.

Answer (score 2):

This is bc of Outlook App adding styling for links.  This is also an issue on Windows 10 and I believe Comcast email.

Try adding this code in your CSS

```
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink {
mso-style-priority:100 !important;
color:#000000 !important;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Comment: After fighting this so many times in HTML emails and finally saying screw Outlook on Windows THIS FINALLY DID IT. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need all those extra tags or `!important` references in inline css. Something like this *should* work, though I get the sense you've already tried it:

```
<a href="#" style="margin:10px 0px 40px 0px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; color: #EF8152; font-weight:300; line-height:15px; font-size:15px; text-align:center; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">
    View in web browser.
</a>
```

Two other things to try:

1. Get rid of the styles for `a` in the `<head>`.
2. If you're inlining any CSS, turn that off / don't do it.

---

If this *still* doesn't work there's been [chatter about this being a bug in Outlook app](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5386-outlook-app-on-ios-turns-links-blue), both Android and iOS apps are mentioned.

Comment: For normal web coding yes you would not use inline styles but for HTML emails you have to inline most everything for older and some newer email clients. It seems counter intuitive, and outdated, but it's just how email is right now. Also styles in the <head> are needed usually for mobile media queries but get ignored by most desktop email clients.